# Idiomatic way to split string to an array by last delimiter existence in every occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8

Let say I want to split string by `,,` e.g

**Input** string-

```
"hello world,,,hello country,,hello city"
```

Expected **Output** array-

```
["hello world,", "hello country", "hello city"]
```

---

If I use `input.split(",,")`

**Result**-

```
["hello world", ",hello country", "hello city"]
```

In the above result the extra comma becomes the part of second string, but I would like it to be the part of first string as shown in expected output.

so technically I want while splitting string like `",,,"` the *first comma* should be the part of first string rather than *last comma* being the part of second string. How can I achieve this it in most simple and idiomatic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex in split, that correspond to: "`,,` not followed by another `,`".

```
    String s = "hello world,,,hello country,,hello city";
    String[] res = s.split(",,(?!,)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); //[hello world,, hello country, hello city]
```

`xxx(?!,)` is a [negative-lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which match only if `,` doesn't appear immediately after the `xxx`.